# How do I make this function recursive?

Tags: python, recursion

I need to use the formula v = (start * 2) + 5 to print the resulting values. The start parameter is the value in which the sequence starts and the count parameter is how many values get printed. I have no idea how to get the base case to get called.

```
def print_sequence_rec(start, count):
        else:
            v = (start * 2) + 5
            print(v, end="")
            print_sequence_rec(start, count + 1)
```

For example, the function print_sequence_rec(2, 5) should print 2 9 23 51 107 219

Answer (score 1):

Make that `count - 1` instead of `+ 1` so that `count` decreases by one each call. The base case is when `count == 0`.

You'll also need to do something with `v`. I suggest passing it to the recursive invocation.

```
def print_sequence_rec(start, count):
    # base case
    if count == 0:
        pass
    # recursive case
    else:
        v = (start * 2) + 5
        print(v, end="")
        print_sequence_rec(v, count - 1)
```

Or more likely you should get rid of it and move the computation to the recursive call:

```
def print_sequence_rec(start, count):
    # base case
    if count == 0:
        pass
    # recursive case
    else:
        print(start, end="")
        print_sequence_rec((start * 2) + 5, count - 1)
```

Comment: It works great except I realized for the output, it needs to print 1 more value than the count. For example, if the count was 5, it would need to print the start value following with 5 digits following the sequence. Thank you!

Comment: changing the base case to `if count == -1` should print the additional value in the sequence

Comment: Or flip it around and put the print and recursion inside an `if count >= 0:` block.

Answer (score 0):

[John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69230989/16746253) does a nice job addressing your question, but this actually seems like a good case to use a generator.

For example...

```
def gen_sequence_rec(start, count):  
    while count >= 0:               
        yield start
        start = (start * 2) + 5
        count -= 1
```

...then you can save the sequence as a list...

```
seq = list(gen_sequence_rec(2,5))

#[2, 9, 23, 51, 107, 219]
```

...and print however you want...

```
print(seq)

[2, 9, 23, 51, 107, 219]

print(' '.join([str(x) for x in seq]))

2 9 23 51 107 219
```